# what is the difference between rel and href and src in HTML

Tags: html, href, src

all of :

href

src

rel

attributes all seems to have same function so why each html element use these different attributes . So what is the function of each of these attributes and when to use each one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`href`*** 
The `href` attribute specifies the location(URL) of any resource that anchor tag points to.

***`src`***

The `src` attribute specifies the location(URL) of any resource that needs to be embedded into the present HTML document. Resourse pointed by `src` attribute is linked to the current document such as img, video, audio, or script. The browser will allocate screen real estate depending upon the physical dimensions of the embedded object. `href` has no such provision.

The `***rel***` attribute defines the relationship that the linked resource has to the document from which it’s referenced. In most cases, this resource will simply be “stylesheet“, which means, not surprisingly, “the referenced document is a `style sheet`.” Related to this value is `alternate`, which is used alongside the `stylesheet` value `(rel="alternate stylesheet")` to indicate that there’s another style associated with the page. In fact, you can define several alternative styles, although the main issue with this approach lies in making it clear to the user that an alternative style sheet is available. In Firefox, you can chose View > Page Style and pick from the available style sheets on offer, but there’s no obvious indication in any browser that these alternatives exist—it’s usually left to the developer to provide some kind of JavaScript-based style switcher that renders as a control on the page. The following markup shows a page that has one main style sheet and two alternatives:

Comment: That certainly answers *how* to use the attributes. But the question remains, why does the HTML spec use both href and src to specify a URL on different tags? There are interesting details of the history of why here https://dev.to/dance2die/href-vs-src-in-html-10l7